# Why does Jenkins shell file copy not work as expected (does not overwrite existing files)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a step in a Jenkins pipeline to copy some source files to the workspace.

```
stage('Copy Files') {
  script {
    echo 'Staging files'
    sh "cp -ar /home/dev/src/ ${env.WORKSPACE}"
  }
}
```

Yet, when I rerun the build it uses the old code. The only solution is to delete the workspace prior to the copy. In a normal Linux file system a copy will overwrite the destination. Why does Jenkins behave differently--i.e., old files are not overwritten? From the syntax it seems like it is just running a shell command, so why does this not have the expected behavior?

Comment: Maybe that shell has noclobber setting enabled?

Answer (score 1):

It is because, Jenkins run on master node and workspace will be on the worker node.

when `checkout scm` and `sh ""` code blocks are in different stages, files will not be save from first stage to other. You should use `stash` & `unstash`. when you stash a directory path, files in that dir will be available to the unstashed step in later stages.

Jenkins doc - [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build)